# Перекрасить платформы в цвета, которые вам больше всего нравятся, используя массив. Для прохода по платформам использовать цикл

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, цвета

можете пожалуйста помочь?Мне нужно с помощью скрипта перекрасить мои платформы в различные цвета.Перепробовал всё и не получается сделать так как нужно:(
Ниже мой код...

```
public SpriteRenderer [] renderers;
 
  void Start()
 {
  for(int i =0;i<renderers.Length;i++)
  {
    float r = UnityEngine.Random.value; 
    float g = UnityEngine.Random.value;
  float b = UnityEngine.Random.value;
  float a = UnityEngine.Random.value;
  Color color = new Color(r,g,b,a);
  renderers[i].color = color;
renderers[0].color = Color.yellow;
renderers[1].color = Color.magenta;
renderers[2].color = Color.green;
renderers[3].color = Color.blue;
renderers[4].color = Color.black;
  }
 }
```

Буду рад если вы поможете сделать скрипт верно(на C#).

Comment: А изначально спрайты белые?

Comment: Да,изначально они белые

Comment: Тогда что именно не получается - перекрасить или что-то другое? Цвета не меняются? Или не получается выполнить условие задачи - перекрасить в цикле с массивами?

Comment: Цвета меняются.У меня не получается перекрасить в цикле с массивами...// как сделать так чтобы этот блок не вызывался несколько раз?
renderers[0].color = Color.yellow;
renderers[1].color = Color.magenta;
renderers[2].color = Color.green;
renderers[3].color = Color.blue;
renderers[4].color = Color.black;

Comment: Создайте еще 1 массив - для цветов. Сколько платформ, столько и цветов. И в цикле panels[i].color = colors[i]

Comment: зачем ты сначала рандомишь цвет, а потом присваиваешь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public SpriteRenderer[] renderers;

void Start () {
    foreach (SpriteRenderer render in renderers)
        render.color = Color.HSVToRGB(Random.value, 1f, 1f); // цвет, насыщенность, яркость
}
```

п.с. в `rgba`, `a` это не цвет, а прозрачность!

Comment: Cпасибо огромное!Я очень долго не мог понять как справиться с этим заданием...Вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 0):

```
public SpriteRenderer[] renderers;

void Start()
{
    for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) //array 0 1 2 3;  4 color blue
    {
        renderers[i].color = Color.blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]